# Deriving Stochastic Differential Equations about Population Dynamics

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations, population-dynamics

This is somewhat of a high-level, I-hardly-know-much-about-the-topic-yet question, but here goes.

I came across online a presentation in which part of it documented deriving an SDE for a population dynamics system between two different groups. In it, the author creates a matrix, $B$, which is another matrix, $V^{\frac{1}{2}}$. See (http://www.nimbios.org/tutorials/TT_stochastic_modeling_talks/eallenUTlect1.pdf, Slide 63)

If I had a system of THREE populations that are very similar to the situation presented in this presentation, would I need to take the cube root of my derived matrix, $V$?

Apologies if this has little appearance of background research -- I haven't encountered SDEs academically but am trying to derive an analog to a discrete-time system of equations and a Monte Carlo simulation I'm working on.

Comment: You don't have to take the cube root. The reason for the square root $V^{1/2}$ at $dW$ (in any dimension) is that its square, $V$, is then a covariance matrix.

Comment: Sounds great! Haven't yet encountered covariance matrices in my studies in a formal capacity, so thanks for the help!